# Импорт списка из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне нужно импортировать список(movie_attr) из файла(parse.py) в главный файл проекта,но у меня никак не получается это сделать.

parse:

```
def top():
    r = requests.get('https://www.kinomania.ru/top/films')
    html = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    movie_cards = html.find_all('div', class_='table-top-item')
    movie_attrs = []
    for movie_card in movie_cards:
        movie_attrs.append({
            'title': movie_card.find('div', class_='table-top-title').get_text(),
            'rating': movie_card.find('span',class_='table-top-info-raiting').get_text()
        })
    for movie_attr in movie_attrs:
        return movie_attr
top()
```

Вот что выдает трэйсбек

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from parse import movie_attr
ImportError: cannot import name 'movie_attr' from 'parse' (/root/Рабочий стол/cinemabot/parse.py)
```

Comment: Список создаётся и виден только пока работает функция, **даже** если вы его вынесете из тела функции вы импортнете его пустым, толку от этого 0

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за совет, я почти разобрался с решением. только я не могу вывести больше одного элемента списка и не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: @AntonElesin return прерывает работу функции. Просто вместо цикла сделайте `return movie_attrs`, а снаружи уже с этим списком делайте то что вам нужно. Я об этом писал в последнем абзаце ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `top` вы значение возвращаете, но при вызове никуда не сохраняете. `return movie_attr` возвращает не переменную, а только ее значение (после вызова `top()` переменная `movie_attr` не становится магическим образом глобальной переменной модуля).

Чтобы можно было получить это значение - его нужно сохранить в переменную:

```
def top():
    ...
    return movie_attr


movie_attr = top()
```

Также вместо импортирования переменной можно имопортировать и вызывать вызывать саму функцию `top` в другом модуле:

```
from parse import top

movie_attr = top()
```

Это удобно, например, если вдруг понадобится вызывать эту функцию с какими-то параметрами.

Также, обратите внимание, что цикл `for` в конце функции `top` возвращает только первое значение из списка `movie_attrs` (через `return` можно вернуть значение только один раз, т.к. `return` прерывает выполнение функции). Удобнее было бы возвращать весь список `movie_attrs` целиком без цикла.